# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

program has crashed at run time.when my code reach to NSMutableArray where I used `arryWithObjects` method to save some objects in it here is my code

```
(NSMutableArray *) NumSysToNumSysMultiplyMetd:(NSString *)DecCode lenthOfDecCode
                                   :(int)length NumSysMultiplyValue
                                   :(int)value
{

NSString * step1 = DecCode;
int Step2 = 0;
NSString *step2s=@"=> ";
int finalAnswer=0;

for (int i=length,j=0; i >=0; i--,j++)
{
    NSString *digit;


    digit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[DecCode characterAtIndex:j]];

    step1 = [step1 stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ * %i^%i +  ",digit,value,i]];

    Step2= [digit integerValue] * pow(value, i);

    step2s= [step2s stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i +",Step2]];

    finalAnswer =finalAnswer +  Step2;

}
NSMutableArray *mut = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:step1,step2s,finalAnswer,nil];
return mut
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to add `finalAnswer` (an `int`) to the `NSMutableArray`.

`int` is **not** an Objective-C object.

Try converting `finalAnswer` to an `NSString` or an `NSNumber` and then store it.

Comment: An NSNumber would be more appropriate, probably

Comment: Nvm, the other objects are strings